# Why won't this imap.select("INBOX") work as expected for this google mail account?

Tags: python, gmail-imap, imaplib

I am working on an app that must log into an email account to process some emails. In this case the email account is being run through the google business suite (so it's not a gmail domain).

The app manages to log into the mail account with this command

```
mail_client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
mail_client.login(user, password)
```

Then I need to go through the inbox, so I have the code

```
mail_client.select("INBOX")
(result, messages) = mail_client.search(None, 'ALL')
```

This results in the error

```
imaplib.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED
```

This is odd because the `select` command did not work, one would have expected an error message relating to that. However, it seems to be OK with the `select` command, but then  in the next line it acts as if nothing is selected.

I have run the following code to get a list of the folders that there are:

```
for i in mail_client.list()[1]:
    print(i)
```

and the output is

```
b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "INBOX"'
b'(\\HasChildren \\Noselect) "/" "[Gmail]"'
b'(\\All \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"'
b'(\\Drafts \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Drafts"'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Important) "/" "[Gmail]/Important"'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Sent) "/" "[Gmail]/Sent Mail"'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Junk) "/" "[Gmail]/Spam"'
b'(\\Flagged \\HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Starred"'
b'(\\HasNoChildren \\Trash) "/" "[Gmail]/Trash"'
```

I have found that the code works if the selected folder is empty. But, the moment there is actually a mail in it, I get the error (even if it used to work while empty). The code also works if the folder is not empty, but the search command would return nothing... as in, `(result, messages) = mail_client.search(None, '(TO "non-existing@email.address")')`... but the moment that the search result would return something, I get the error.

But I need to specifically search the Inbox.

I've also modified the code a bit to check:

```
status, message = mail_client.select('INBOX')
print(f"status is {status}")
print(f"message is {message}")
```

and this gives

```
status is OK
message is [b'3']
```

In my search for a solution I have found various posts where the issue turned out to be folder names with spaces in them, but I could not find any one who had the same problem as me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Turn on imaplib tracing (debug=5 or something to the constructor?  You’d have to check the doc here)  I expect you’re somehow getting disconnected, or the login did not actually succeed.  However, the log can help you/us figure out what happened between those two steps.